# Extracting a string from one column into another in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have an example data frame like the one below.

| ID | File |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11_213.csv |
| 2 | 13_256.csv |
| 3 | 11_223.csv |
| 4 | 12_389.csv |
| 5 | 14_456.csv |
| 6 | 12_345.csv |

And I want to add another column based on the string between the underscore and the period to get a data frame that looks something like this.

| ID | File | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11_213.csv | 213 |
| 2 | 13_256.csv | 256 |
| 3 | 11_223.csv | 223 |
| 4 | 12_389.csv | 389 |
| 5 | 14_456.csv | 456 |
| 6 | 12_345.csv | 345 |

I think I need to use the str_extract feature within stringr but I am not sure what notation to use for my pattern.  For example when I use:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate("Group" = str_extract(File, "[^_]+"))
```

I get the all the information before the underscore like this:

| ID | File | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11_213.csv | 11 |
| 2 | 13_256.csv | 13 |
| 3 | 11_223.csv | 11 |
| 4 | 12_389.csv | 12 |
| 5 | 14_456.csv | 14 |
| 6 | 12_345.csv | 12 |

But that is not what I want.  What should I use instead of "[^_]+" to get just the stuff between the underscore and the period?  Thanks!

Comment: You need `str_extract(File, "(?<=_)(\\d+)(?=\\.)")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to extract the digits (`\\d+`) that succeeds a `_` and precedes a `.` with `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(Group = str_extract(File, "(?<=_)(\\d+)(?=\\.)")
```

---

Or another option is to remove the substring with `str_remove` i.e to match characters (`.*`) including the `_` or (`|`) characters from `.` onwards (`.` can match any character in regex mode - which is by default, so we escape `\\` it for literal matching)

```
df <- df %>%
        mutate(Group = str_remove_all(File, ".*_|\\..*"))
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `gsub`

```
transform(
  df,
  Group = gsub(".*_(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", File)
)
```

gives

```
  ID       File Group
1  1 11_213.csv   213
2  2 13_256.csv   256
3  3 11_223.csv   223
4  4 12_389.csv   389
5  5 14_456.csv   456
6  6 12_345.csv   345
```